# Facebook APP should re ask for permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app which accesses the user data and publishes on its wall as well as on my site.  When app gets the user info it is stored in DB. Now if a user delets the publish permission i want my app to re ask for permission but somehow it does not asks for permission and dosent posts on wall but posts on my site.   What can i do??

Comment: Are you including `publish_actions` or `publish_stream` in the `scope` parameter in your calls to the Auth dialog?

Comment: I am including publish stream..